# MySQL inner join single query

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, inner-join

I have 2 tables :

```
users : contains id and name
friends : contains id1 and id2
```

Let's suppose I have this data in the `users` table :

```
id : 1 , name : FinalDestiny
id : 2 , name : George
```

And this data in the `friends` table:

```
id1: 1 , id2: 2
```

So this means that 1 is friend with 2.

I need with one single query to say that `id1` is friend with `id2`( but I need the names) Like: FinalDestiny is friend with George. I have to make one mysql inner or left join but I don't know how

Comment: Thanks for formatting. Its much readable now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use aliases and double-join the user table with the friends table:

```
    SELECT `u1`.`name` `name1`, `u2`.`name` `name2`
      FROM `friends` `f`
INNER JOIN `users` `u1`
        ON `f`.`id1` = `u1`.`id`
INNER JOIN `users` `u2`
        ON `f`.`id2` = `u2`.`id`
```

Comment: @FinalDestiny what exactly does not work? i checked, but could not find a typo …

Comment: @FinalDestiny i just recreated your tables locally and tested my query. it works for me

Answer (score 2):

```
Select F1.Name,
       F2.Name
From Friends F
INNER JOIN USER F1 ON F.ID1 = F1.id
INNER JOIN USER F2 ON F.ID2 = F2.id
```

Explanation:

As friend is composition of two user, friend1 and friend2, so we will try to join friend with 2 user, 1 user table corresponding to ID1 and other to ID2 getting information for both the friends from respective user table.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether you can do it. But this is the closest that I could get it for you.

`select u1.name, u2.name from users u1, users u2, friends f where u1.id = f.id1 and u2.id = f.id2`

Comment: it is just like defining variables in languages. like  `int i` which equivalents to `users u1`. `users` is the table name here and `u1` is the alias here.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to join on your `users` table twice.

```
SELECT 
   u1.name AS FirstPerson
  ,u2.name AS SecondPerson 
FROM 
  friends f
INNER JOIN
  users u1
ON
  u1.id = f.id1
INNER JOIN
  users u2
ON
  f.id2 = u2.id
```

Comment: Table aliases for the users table.  We need to reference the same table twice.  By providing aliases, we can qualify .name with the alias we want to pull the name from.

u1 = users table as joined on id1.  u2 = users table as joined on id2.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to query this without the explicit use of joins using something along the lines of...

```
SELECT * FROM (friends, users AS u1, users AS u2) WHERE
friends.id1=u1.id AND friends.id2=u2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to select from friends and join the users table twice (for each friend)

```
SELECT u1.Name, u2.Name 
FROM Friends as fr 
  INNER JOIN users as u1 on fr.Id1 = u1.id
  INNER JOIN users as u2 on fr.Id2 = u2.id
```

Comment: @FinalDestiny: not into pop music?

Comment: Hmm I don't understand your query...Can you try to do it using my tables? users and friends :\